# Fast way variables into dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a bunch of variables var1, var2, var3, ..., var99.

I like to have a dict where the name is the key and the key refers to the value of the variable.
Currently I have to type

```
{
'var1': var1,
'var2': var2,
'var3': var3
...
}
```

Is there a faster way? Also I prefere pythonic answers of cause ;)

Edit: An example I like to use

```
noise_std = np.mean(np.std(noise, axis=2))
noise_max = np.mean(np.max(noise, axis=2))
noise_min = np.mean(np.min(noise, axis=2))
noise_unique = len(torch.unique((torch.from_numpy(noise))))
noise_diff = (torch.sum(torch.abs(noise)) / (test_input.shape[1] * test_input.shape[2]) / 250).item()


result = {
    'id_file': id_file,
    'noise_unique': float(noise_unique),
    'noise_min': float(noise_min),
    'noise_max': float(noise_max),
    'noise_std': float(noise_std),
    'noise_diff': float(noise_diff)
    'snr_std': float(snr_std),
    'snr_mean': float(snr_mean),
    'macro_auc': float(macro_auc),
    'model_name': model_name,
    'n_iter': n_iter,
    'epsilon': epsilon
}
```

(Note: Some variables are from the parameters, later I need some of the variables. I just like to clear the code)

Edit 2: I like to a command like into_dict(macro_auc, n_iter, epsilon, snr_std)

Comment: "I have a bunch of variables var1, var2, var3, ..., var99" - Oh oh... You probably shouldn't have that in the first place. How did you get them? Can't you have them in a list or dict from the start?

Comment: The answer is to not have a bunch of variables in the first place, and to instead have a list, or to put those values directly into the dict, or something.  How do you currently generate those variables?

Comment: @Thiery var1, var2, are just aliases. The names arent important.

Comment: I need the variables otherwise so it would be annoying to refer the dict. Also I like to return a dict.

Comment: Can you show your actual code?

Comment: If you already know that you have a variable called *var1*, why do you need its literal name in a dictionary? As an aside, have you looked at what *locals()* and *globals()* provide you with?

Comment: @Olvin I return the dict and save the data in a file.

Comment: Pedantic but important note: the key does not refer to the variable; it refers to the *value* of the variable at the time the `dict` was constructed.

Comment: What do you then use `result` for? If you're just wanting to organise your data, perhaps consider using a dataclass https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html instead of a dict?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [globals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) and [locals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) to get a dict of global or local variables.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pprint

var1 = 1
var2 = "hello"

def my_func(arg):
    local_var = "there"
    print("globals:")
    pprint.pprint(globals())

    print("locals:")
    pprint.pprint(locals())

def main():
    my_func(99)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
{'...': 'redacted',
 'main': <function main at 0x10b767430>,
 'my_func': <function my_func at 0x10b5ac0d0>,
 'pprint': <module 'pprint' from '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/pprint.py'>,
 'var1': 1,
 'var2': 'hello'}
locals:
{'arg': 99, 'local_var': 'there'}
```